# Same length sub arrays

Tags: code-golf, array

## Background:

Here's a little simple challenge. You want to be able to find out whether the arrays inside an array have the same length.

## Input:

Your input should consist of exactly one array *(this is the value passed to the function, not a user input)*. Your function takes exactly 1 parameter.  It could contain arrays or be empty. No error checking needed, assume only list is ever passed in. Assume a 1-D array such as `[1]` or `[1,2,3,4,5]` is never passed in.

## Output:

Return `true` if all the list elements have the same length, `false` if they don't, and the parameter itself if the list is empty (or null if your language doesn't support multiple return types).

#### Some test cases:

```
List: [] - [] (or null/your language equivalent)
List: [[1], [1], [2]] - True
List: [[1]] - True
List: [[1, 2, 3, 4]] - True
List: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2], [12, 314123]] - False
List: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1]] - False
```

No std(in/out) input/output needed (however, it is allowed, just not required!), the function only needs to return boolean values `true` or `false`; or the parameter itself if the function is passed an empty list (or null/your language equivalent). Only one return value is returned.

## Rules:

Shortest byte count wins, only function is necessary (full programs are allowed if you desire).

Comment: what if we don't have a null type?

Comment: @Maltysen Good question, I'll change the rules to accommodate such languages.

Comment: what if we can't return different types (Arrays / Booleans)?

Comment: @nimi To be totally fair this question was designed with multiple return types in mind. Having to return either an array or boolean is what adds to the challenge imo. Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: As the parameter is only returned when it is empty, how about some kind of option type like Haskell's `Maybe`, i.e. `Nothing` for the empty list and `Just True`/`Just False` else? Or `Either` -> `Left []` / `Right True`. Basically any wrapper that can combine two types.

Comment: Are the sublist elements always going to be positive integers?

Comment: @nimi That works well as there would be 3 different returns values in that case.

Comment: @Neil The sub lists elements can be of any type, your code should have no knowledge of the context lists, just compares their length!

Comment: The special-case output for the empty list, especially one of a different type, is an extraneous task that makes solutions needlessly uglier.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Usually we first post a question in the [**Sandbox for Proposed Challenges**](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges). That way we can first get feedback and discussions to make the question close to perfect before posting it here. It's advisable to keep it in the Sandbox for ±72 hours so enough people can give recommendations, remarks and ask questions regarding your challenge. More info can be found in the Sandbox itself. (That being said, it looks like a good question, but in the Sandbox people often ask about edge/cases.)

Comment: Actually my sublist question was a red herring; I had got my lists and sublists confused.

Comment: Are full programs allowed?

Comment: @xnor It's part of the difficulty of the challenge, but I'll keep that in mind next time I design a question.

Comment: @Mego You can if you would like, but I thought I'd make the requirements more language agnostic, and only ask for a function.

Comment: @TimmyD To keep it simple! Only a function needed, no need to pipe in input from any outside source.

Comment: @mrdomoboto The default is to allow [either a program or function](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/42963) since one or the other is easier in some languages. Same with the standard I/O methods I linked earlier. Restricting those defaults actually makes the challenge *less* language agnostic.

Comment: Also ... **Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf!** I hope you enjoy your time here. :-)

Comment: @TimmyD Okay, I'll update the requirements with these edge cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Pyth - <s>7</s> 5 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @FryAmTheEggman.*

And I was the one who told @issacg to remove the `q` default...

```
?QqCC
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3FQqCC&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%5D%0A%5B%5B1%5D%2C+%5B1%5D%2C+%5B2%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%5D%2C+%5B2%5D%2C+%5B12%2C+314123%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%5D%2C+%5B1%5D%5D&debug=0).

Comment: I think `?QqCC` works.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman nice!

Answer (score 9):

## Python 2, 31

```
lambda l:l and l==zip(*zip(*l))
```

This requires the lists to be lists of tuples. `zip` Drops extra elements if the input was ragged, so double zipping is only a noop if the lists all have the same length.

[Try it here](https://ideone.com/r4t3Ib)

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript ES6, <s>44</s> <s>43</s> 42 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to @Neil

```
a=>a[0]?!a.some(b=>b.length-a[0].length):a
```

Alternative solutions

```
a=>a[0]?a.every(b=>b.length==a[0].length):a // 43
a=>a[0]?new Set(a.map(b=>b.length)).size==1:a // 45
a=>a[0]?Math.max(...a.map(b=>b.length))==a[0].length:a // 54
a=>a[0]?[a[0].length,...a].reduce((b,d)=>b==d.length):a // 55, doesn't work as intended
```

Somehow the stacksnippet doesn't print `[]`, try it in your console for the actual result.

```js
f=
a=>a[0]?a.every(b=>b.length==a[0].length):a

z.innerHTML = [
  [],
  [[1], [1], [2]],
  [[1]],
  [[1, 2, 3, 4]],
  [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2], [12, 314123]],
  [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1]]
].map(m=>JSON.stringify(f(m))).join`<br>`
```

```html
<pre id=z>
```

(yay for crossed out 44)

Comment: Your second alternative won't work, `reduce` uses the result of the previous function call as the first parameter to the next. Even if it did work, `c` costs you a byte. `c` costs you 4 bytes in your third alternative, since it's an unused variable.

Comment: I think I shaved off a byte: `a=>a[0]?!a.some(b=>b.length-a[0].length):a`

Comment: "Somehow" == in JavaScript `[].toString()` returns an empty string.

Comment: `Array.prototype.toString()` is equivalent to `Array.prototype.join()` with no arguments, that's why.

Comment: Try wrapping the array in `JSON.stringify` to display it correctly.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Good idea, thanks

Comment: `Set` solution `==1` => `<2`

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
L€E⁸ȧ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=TOKCrEXigbjIpwrDh-KCrMWS4bmY&input=&args=W10sIFtbMV0sIFsxXSwgWzJdXSwgW1sxXV0sIFtbMSwgMiwgMywgNF1dLCBbWzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDVdLCBbMl0sIFsxMiwgMzE0MTIzXV0sIFtbMSwgMiwgMywgNF0sIFsxXV0)

#### How it works

```
L€E⁸ȧ  Monadic link. Argument: A (list)

L€     Map length over the list.
  E    Test if all elements are equal.
   ⁸ȧ  Take the logical AND of A and the resulting Boolean.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 17 bytes

```perl6
{$_??[==] $_!!$_}
```

`[==] $_` does a reduce of the input (`$_`) with `&infix:<==>`. `&infix:<==>` is a Numeric operator so it coerces its inputs to Numeric. The rest is just the ternary operator `??` `!!`.

This is roughly equivalent to

```perl6
sub ( $_ ) {
  if $_ {
    # the ｢map｣ is for clarity, it is not needed
    $_.map(*.elems).reduce(&infix:<==>)
    # ｢[OP] List｣ is actually smarter than ｢List.reduce(&infix:«OP»)｣
    # as it takes into account operator chaining, and associativity
  } else {
    $_
  }
}
```

#### Test:

```perl6
#! /usr/bin/env perl6

use v6.c;
use Test;

# put it into the lexical namespace for clarity
my &same-elems = {$_??[==] $_!!$_}

my @tests = (
  [] => [],
  [[1], [1], [2]] => True,
  [[1],] => True,
  [[1, 2, 3, 4],] => True,
  [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2], [12, 314123]] => False,
  [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1]] => False,
);

plan +@tests;

for @tests -> ( :key(@input), :value($expected) ) {
  is same-elems(@input), $expected, @input.perl
}
```

```
1..6
ok 1 - []
ok 2 - [[1], [1], [2]]
ok 3 - [[1],]
ok 4 - [[1, 2, 3, 4],]
ok 5 - [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2], [12, 314123]]
ok 6 - [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Swift 3](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/597a1a65dc0b5b77d1ce1f1e) - 47 Bytes

```
{$0.isEmpty ?nil:Set($0.map{$0.count}).count<2}
```

To invoke, first assign it to a variable:

```
 let f: ([[Any]]) -> Bool? = {$0.isEmpty ?nil:Set($0.map{$0.count}).count<2}
 f([[1], [1,2], [1,2,3]])
```

Comment: Is the initial space required?

Comment: Nope, that was just a typo. It wasn't in my letter count anyway

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 22 bytes

```
a@{}={};a@b_:=ArrayQ@b
```

The requirement of `a[{}] == {}` ruins everything and prevents a 6 byte solution of the built-in `ArrayQ`, since in Mathematica a zero length array is also an array.

Comment: I don't have my mathematica rpi running atm, but IIRC, you can save by special casing `{}` by doing `a@b_:=b&&ArrayQ@b`

Comment: @Maltysen That doesn't seem to work, it'll always return the array if it is an array then (`b&&c` will always return `b` if `c` evaluates to `True`).

Comment: why does it do that? shouldn't it return c if b is true?

Comment: @Maltysen Your statement is the inverse of mine and is also true. I'm referring to `a@{} -> {} && ArrayQ@{} -> {} && True -> {}`. This is desirable. But let `b = {{1},{2},{3}}`, then `a@b -> b && ArrayQ@b -> b && True -> b -> {{1},{2},{3}}` whereas we need `True` here.

Comment: oic, can you do instead then `{}&&stuff`?

Comment: @Maltysen I'm not seeing how that would be helpful.

Comment: I guess mathematica's short-circuiting is just weird and I'm not understanding it...sorry

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 33 bytes

```julia
!x=[]==x?x:diff(map(endof,x))⊆0
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=IXg9W109PXg_eDpkaWZmKG1hcChlbmRvZix4KSniioYwCgpmb3IgeCBpbiAoCiAgICBBbnlbXSwKICAgIEFueVtbMV0sIFsxXSwgWzJdXSwKICAgIEFueVtbMV1dLAogICAgQW55W1sxLCAyLCAzLCA0XV0sCiAgICBBbnlbWzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDVdLCBbMl0sIFsxMiwgMzE0MTIzXV0sCiAgICBBbnlbWzEsIDIsIDMsIDRdLCBbMV1dCikKICAgIHByaW50bG4oIXgpCmVuZA&input=)

#### How it works

We redefine the unary operator **!** for this task.

If **x** is the empty array, we simply return **x**.

Else, we map `endof` (equivalent to `length`) over the arrays in **x** and compute the differences of consecutive lengths with `diff`. If all length are equal, this will generate an array of **0**'s. Otherwise, there will be non-zero numbers in the result.

Finally, `⊆0` tests if all differences are **0** and return the corresponding Boolean.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <s>48</s> 46 bytes

```
f[]=Nothing
f x|h:t<-length<$>x=Just$all(==h)t
```

Wraps the result in the `Maybe` type and returns `Nothing` if the input is the empty list and `Just True`/`Just False` otherwise.

Usage example:

```
*Main> map f [[],[[1],[2],[3]],[[1]],[[1,2,3,4]],[[1,2,3,4,5],[2],[12,314123]],[[1,2,3,4],[1]]]
[Nothing,Just True,Just True,Just True,Just False,Just False]
```

How it works:

```
f[]=Nothing                   -- empty input
f x                           -- otherwise
   |(h:t)<-length<$>x         -- map length function over the input and bind h
                              -- to the first element and t to rest of the list
          =     all(==h)t     -- return whether all values in t equal h
           Just$              -- wrapped in the Maybe type
```

Edit: @Lynn saved two bytes. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like can drop the parens around `h:t`.

Comment: @Lynn: Wow. I don't think I've ever tried to drop parens in a pattern match.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
.v|:ladl1
```

Returns `true` or `false` or the empty list.

#### Explanation

```
.v      Unify the output with the input if it's the empty list
|       Or
:la     Apply length to each element of the input
   d    Remove all duplicates
    l1  The length of the resulting list is 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 27 bytes

`->i{!i.map(&:size).uniq[1]}`

#### Test:

```
s = ->i{!i.map(&:size).uniq[1]}
s[[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1]]]
=> false
s[[[1, 2, 3, 4]]]
=> true
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, <s>145</s> <s>129</s> <s>107</s> <s>106</s> <s>103</s> <s>93</s> 77 bytes

Loads of bytes saved thanks to *@Frozn*, and by using `Object` as return-type, we can comply with OP's rules of returning the input-array when the array is empty, despite Java's one-return-type-only nature regarding methods.

```java
m->{int f=1;for(var a:m)f=m[0].length!=a.length?0:f;return m.length<1?m:f>0;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##rU9Pa4MwFL/7Kd5uClaM7cnM9hOsPfQoHtI06XQmlhgtQ/LZ3XOVbofBEAohvOT3fv8q1rNVdf4Yec3aFt5YqQcPoNRWGMm4gP30BDicKsEtcB@RvMgLUAFFwHl4tZbZksMeNGQwqtV2wCWQGaGyMX7PDLBUBTJTeVxEtdAX@/6SsXnaxamkRtjOaFDz3yvZqVRuY@pGOhlcu1ONBrNP35RnUBjUP1pT6guGYcE95fGztUJFTWejK0K21r6OuK/FbWqE9niC7@D/7mLHuybAQFz4x5g4t0ALmcvWwyRch5tFpEfImfsr6k8BhMiGJOvnKD9aOc@NXw)

**Explanation:**

```java
m->{                  // Method with integer-matrix parameter and Object return-type
  int f=1;            //  Flag-integer, starting at 1
  for(var a:m)        //  Loop over the rows of the matrix
    f=m[0].length!=a.length?
                      //   If the length of the first and current row aren't the same:
       0              //    Change `f` to 0
      :               //   Else:
       f;             //    Leave `f` the same
  return m.length<1?  //  If there is only one row:
          m           //   Return the input-matrix as result
         :            //  Else:
          f>0;}       //   Return whether the flag `f` is still 1 as boolean
```

Comment: I don't understand why the `p = a[x].length` is necessary as it seems to don't change the value of `p`

Comment: @Frozn Ah, you're completely right, I screwed up!.. I've removed it. Thanks.

Comment: Alright, I think you can get rid of some characters by changing the for-loop to a for each. Didn't tested it just wrote it on a piece of paper and it looked a bit shorter. Oh and in addition you can remove `l` so it will get even shorter.

Comment: @Frozn True. I had the for-loop because of the previous `p = a[x].length;`, but now I can indeed use a foreach-loop instead. So, changed yet again. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I changed the requirements, null or the parameter is fine.

Comment: It's me again, I claim you can change the return type to Object to save an additional character. Also with the forearm loop you can remove the first if statement and move it to the end of the function as a ternary like `return a.length < 0 ? null : 1 > 0`

Comment: As the OP allows to return the parameter itself you can replace the return of `null` with `a`. This will save some more characters, so you could come down to 93.

Comment: @Frozn Sorry for the late response.. I somehow read past your comments. Edited and thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v2+, 53 bytes

```
param($a)if($a){($a|%{$_.count}|select -u).count-eq1}
```

This presumes that [standard I/O methods](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963) and both [programs and functions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/42963) are allowed. Additionally, in PowerShell, the concept of "returning" an empty array is meaningless -- it's converted to `$null` as soon as it leaves scope -- and so it is the equivalent of returning nothing, which is what is done here.

We take input `$a`, and `if` it's non-empty we collect all the `.count`s of each sub-array. We pipe that to `Select-Object` with the `-u`nique flag, take *that* `.count` and verify that it's `-eq`ual to `1`. Returns Boolean `$true` or `$false`. If the input is the empty array, returns nothing (i.e., `$null`).

#### Examples

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\same-length-sub-arrays.ps1 ((1),(2),(3))
True

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\same-length-sub-arrays.ps1 ((1),(2),(3,4))
False

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\same-length-sub-arrays.ps1 @()

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> (.\same-length-sub-arrays.ps1 @()).GetType()
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ (.\same-length-sub-arrays.ps1 @()).GetType()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> (.\same-length-sub-arrays.ps1 @())-eq$null
True
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 45 bytes

```
lambda x:x and min(x,key=len)==max(x,key=len)
```

Comment: 5 bytes shorter: `f=lambda x:x and len(set(map(len,x)))<2`

Comment: also, yours doesn't work on `[]`

Comment: You should return the array if it's empty.

Comment: @Maltysen Thanks for the tip. Feel free to post that as an answer, since it's a totally different approach and I didn't come up with it.

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 51 bytes

```
@(x)repmat(2>n(unique(cellfun(n=@numel,x))),n(x)>0)
```

[**Online Demo**](http://ideone.com/91oCds)

**Explanation**

Loops through the input (a cell array) and determines the number of elements in each entry `numel`, then from this array of the number of elements, we ensure that there is only one unique value: `2 > numel(unique(numberOfElements))`. This will give us the boolean we want. Unfortunately, it is difficult to yield an empty array efficiently so in order to deal with the case of an empty input, we use `repmat` to repeat this boolean value `N` times where `N` is the number of subarrays in the input. If the input is empty this repeats the boolean value `0` times leading to `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

### Actually, 18 bytes

```
`♂l╔l;Y"[].⌂"£n=1`
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=YOKZgmzilZRsO1kiW10u4oyCIsKjbj0xYMaS&input=W10) (calls the function with `ƒ`)

Explanation:

```
`♂l╔l;Y"[].⌂"£n=1`  push a function:
 ♂l                   map length over input
   ╔l                 uniquify
     ;Y               1 if list is empty else 0
       "[].⌂"£n       call this function that many times:
        [].             print an empty list
           ⌂            exit
               =1     1 if length of unique list equals 1 else 0
```

If the function-only requirement is lifted, the equivalent program works for 15 bytes:

```
♂l╔l;Y`[].⌂`n=1
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=4pmCbOKVlGw7WWBbXS7ijIJgbj0x&input=W10)

Answer (score 1):

### 05Ab1E, 12 bytes

```
Dg0Qië€gÙg1Q
```

**Explained**

```
Dg0Qi          # if empty list, return input
     ë         # else
      €g       # map length over list
        Ùg1Q   # check if length of uniquified list is 1
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RGcwUWnDq-KCrGfDmWcxUQ&input=W1sxXSwgWzFdLCBbMiwgM11d)

Answer (score 1):

### F#, 78 bytes

```
function
|[]->None
|x->Seq.forall(fun y->Seq.length y=Seq.length x.[0])x|>Some
```

Output is the [F# Option type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.option%5B%27t%5D-union-%5Bfsharp%5D). If the input is empty output is None, else it's Some bool, where the bool value indicates whether all the sub-arrays are of equal length.

```
// F# Interactive
let f = 
    function
    |[]->None
    |x->Seq.forall(fun y->Seq.length y=Seq.length x.[0])x|>Some;;

val f : _arg1:#seq<'b> list -> bool option

> f [[0;1];[2];[3]];;
val it : bool option = Some false
> f [[0;1];[2;3];];;
val it : bool option = Some true
> f [];;
val it : bool option = None
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 26 bytes

```
]`(1=[:#@~.#@>@>)@.(*@#@>)
```

Since J doesn't support ragged arrays, I will use boxed arrays instead. It returns `1` for true, `0` for false, and the input if empty.

### Usage

```
   f =: ]`(1=[:#@~.#@>@>)@.(*@#@>)

   NB. Boxed array representing [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2], [12, 314123]]
   < 1 2 3 4 ; 2 ; 12 314123
┌─────────────────────┐
│┌───────┬─┬─────────┐│
││1 2 3 4│2│12 314123││
│└───────┴─┴─────────┘│
└─────────────────────┘
   f < 1 2 3 4 ; 2 ; 12 314123
0
   NB. The empty list
   a:
┌┐
││
└┘
   f a:
┌┐
││
└┘
   f < 1 ; 1 ; 2
1
   f < < 1
1
   f < < 1 2 3 4
1
   f < 1 2 3 4 ; 1
0
```

Answer (score 1):

## Retina, 35 bytes

If only `[]` could return true or false. Returning a 3rd value makes it so much longer.

```
\[]
xx
\d|],

M`^\[(\[,*)\1*]]|x
2
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XFtdCnh4ClxkfF0sCgpNYF5cWyhcWywqKVwxKl1dfHgKMgo&input=W1sxLDIsMyw0LDVdLFsyXSxbMTIsMzE0MTIzXV0)

This is the core program. It removes digits and occurrences of `],`, then matches if the number of commas is the same after each `[`. It would return `0` for `[]`. The code above varies because I added a check for an empty list to make it match twice, then I replace `2` with nothing for a null return.

```
\d|],

^\[(\[,*)\1*]]
```

Answer (score 1):

### APL, 13 bytes

```
1=(×∘⍴⍴≢)∪≢¨⎕
```

In English:

- compute the unique of the tallies of each of the subarrays;
- reshape the result with the signum of its shape: if its an empty vector, it remains an empty vector;
- is it equal to 1?

Comment: There's a bug: if the input is the empty list, you should return the empty list instead of 0 or 1. This returns 0.

Comment: @marinus, you are absolutely right: I didn't read carefully enough the specs. Let's see if it's worth trying to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

### C#, 80 bytes

Im checking length 4 times in this golf. i wish there was a better way to be honest.

```
bool f(List<int[]>a){return a.Where(m=>m.Length==a[0].Length).Count()==a.Count;}
```

alternative version also 80 bytes..

```
bool f(List<int[]>a){return a.Where(m=>m.Length==a[0].Length).SequenceEqual(a);}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Prolog, 40

```
m([],L).
m([H|T],L):-length(H,L),m(T,L).
```

Provide a true/false answer when calling `m(X,L)` for some input `X`.

Answer (score 0):

## APL, 13 bytes

```
{(×⍴⍵)↑⍵≡↓↑⍵}
```

Explanation:

- `↓↑⍵`: turn the list of arrays into a matrix, and then turn the matrix back into a list of arrays. Because a matrix has to be rectangular, short arrays will be padded with zeroes to match the longest.
- `⍵≡`: see if the result is equal to the input. This is only the case if no zeroes have been added, which means all the sublists were the same length.
- `×⍴⍵`: take the sign of the length of `⍵`, which is `0` if `⍵` is empty and `1` if not.
- `↑`: take the first 0 or 1 items from the result depending on whether the array was empty or not.

Comment: Turn it into a train to save 4 bytes: `×∘⍴↑⊢≡↓∘↑`. Btw, will I see you in Glasgow?

Comment: @Adám: hopefully, if nothing goes wrong, I will indeed come to Glasgow. But when you have improvements to my posts, it is better to suggest them as edits officially, that way you will get part of the reputation for subsequent upvotes. I don't want to just copy your improvements into my answers without you getting any benefit from it, it feels like cheating.

Comment: @marinus Suggesting golfing edits to an answer is against site policy. All such edits should be rejected as "causes harm" or "conflicts with author's intent".

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 40 bytes

```
#(if(not-empty %)(apply =(map count %)))
```

Yay for suitable language features :)